# Multiple conditions in a CASE statement

Tags: postgresql

I want to assess whether certain conditions are met and then return a certain text. I'm using the CASE syntax, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the most practical way to do this. Also because certain conditions have to match additional conditions (the WHEN statement that returns 'Delay'). Even though it looks messy, it does work, except for the last criteria in the 'Delay' statement.

This is my current CASE statement:

```
    CASE
    WHEN
    (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date >= (p.fecha_prevista_entrega + INTERVAL '30 minutes')) 
    OR (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date < (os.rider_accepted + INTERVAL '5 minutes'))
    THEN 'Not Paid - Cancelled' 

    WHEN
    (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date <= (p.fecha_prevista_entrega + INTERVAL '30 minutes')) 
    AND (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date >= p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)
    THEN 'Paid - Cancelled'

    WHEN
    (u.first_name ILIKE '%LKF%' AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)/60) > '15'))
    OR (u.first_name NOT ILIKE '%LKF%' AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)/60) > '30'))

    AND (
    ((od.preorder = '0' AND od.order_comment ILIKE '%' || u.first_name || '%') AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)/60) < '15')

    OR        
    ((od.preorder = '0' AND od.order_comment NOT ILIKE '%' || u.first_name || '%') AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)/60) < '20')

    OR
    (od.preorder = '1' AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM p.fecha_prevista_entrega - os.rider_assigned)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM p.fecha_prevista_entrega - os.rider_assigned)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM p.fecha_prevista_entrega - os.rider_assigned)/60) > '30')

    OR
    ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)/60) > '15')

    OR
    ((os.rider_at_restaurant >= (p.fecha_entrega_repartidor + INTERVAL '3 minutes')) AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)/60) < '15'))


    )
    THEN 'Delay'

    ELSE 'None' END AS payment_adj
```

This part of the statement does not work:

```
    OR
    ((os.rider_at_restaurant >= (p.fecha_entrega_repartidor + INTERVAL '3 minutes')) AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)/60) < '15'))
```

I've crosschecked several results that show 'Delay', but should not show it because they don't match this condition.

Here's the full query

```
WITH order_steps AS                         
(                       
    SELECT pedido_id,                       
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 0 THEN created_at END) AS rider_assigned,                        
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 1 THEN created_at END) AS rider_viewed,                      
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 2 THEN created_at END) AS rider_accepted,                        
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 3 THEN created_at END) AS         rider_at_restaurant,                       
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 4 THEN created_at END) AS food_picked_up,                        
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 5 THEN created_at END) AS rider_at_customer,                     
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 6 THEN created_at END) AS food_delivered,                        
    MAX(CASE WHEN situacion  = 10 THEN created_at END) AS unknown_status                        
    FROM dwh.tracking_motero t                      
    GROUP BY 1                      
    ORDER BY 1,2                        
),                      
    assigned_riders AS (                        
    WITH rider_assignments AS (                     
    SELECT mp.pedido_id, mp.motero_id, mp.created_at, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mp.pedido_id ORDER BY mp.created_at DESC) AS last_assignments                     
    FROM dwh.motero_pedido mp                       
    )                       
    SELECT pedido_id, motero_id FROM rider_assignments                      
    WHERE last_assignments = 1                      
    )                       

    SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN
    (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date >= (p.fecha_prevista_entrega + INTERVAL '30 minutes')) 
    OR (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date < (os.rider_accepted + INTERVAL '5 minutes'))
    THEN 'Not Paid - Cancelled' 

    WHEN
    (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date <= (p.fecha_prevista_entrega + INTERVAL '30 minutes')) 
    AND (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date >= p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)
    THEN 'Paid - Cancelled'

    WHEN
    (u.first_name ILIKE '%LKF%' AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)/60) > '15'))
    OR (u.first_name NOT ILIKE '%LKF%' AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)/60) > '30'))

    AND (
    ((od.preorder = '0' AND od.order_comment ILIKE '%' || u.first_name || '%') AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)/60) < '15')

    OR        
    ((od.preorder = '0' AND od.order_comment NOT ILIKE '%' || u.first_name || '%') AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.rider_assigned - od.date)/60) < '20')

    OR
    (od.preorder = '1' AND (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM p.fecha_prevista_entrega - os.rider_assigned)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM p.fecha_prevista_entrega - os.rider_assigned)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM p.fecha_prevista_entrega - os.rider_assigned)/60) > '30')

    OR
    ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega)/60) > '15')

    OR
    ((os.rider_at_restaurant >= (p.fecha_entrega_repartidor + INTERVAL '3 minutes')) AND ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)*60+EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)+EXTRACT(SECOND FROM os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)/60) < '15'))


    )
    THEN 'Delay'



    ELSE 'None' END AS payment_adj,
    p.id AS urban_ninja_id,                         
    o.order_fp_code AS order_code,                      
    p.total AS order_amount,                        
    p.paymenttype_name,                     
    u.first_name AS rider_code,                     
    p.direccion AS delivery_address,                        
    p.fecha_entrega_repartidor AS expected_pick_up_time,                        
    p.fecha_prevista_entrega AS expected_delivery_time,                     
    od.date AS order_creation_date,                     
    os.rider_assigned,                      
    os.rider_viewed,                        
    os.rider_accepted,                      
    os.rider_at_restaurant,                     
    os.food_picked_up,                      
    os.rider_at_customer,                       
    os.food_delivered,                      
    os.unknown_status,                      
    st.id AS status_id,                     
    st.code AS status_code,                     
    st.title AS status,                     
    ve.title AS vendor,                     
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_assigned-od.date)*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.rider_assigned-od.date)+EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.rider_assigned-od.date)/60 AS dispatching_time,                     
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_viewed-os.rider_assigned)*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.rider_viewed-os.rider_assigned)+EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.rider_viewed-os.rider_assigned)/60 AS rider_reaction_time,                      
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_accepted-os.rider_viewed)*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.rider_accepted-os.rider_viewed)+EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.rider_accepted-os.rider_viewed)/60 AS rider_acceptance_time,                        
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_at_restaurant-os.rider_accepted)*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.rider_at_restaurant-os.rider_accepted)+EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.rider_at_restaurant-os.rider_accepted)/60 AS rider_driving_to_restaurant_time,                        
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_picked_up-os.rider_at_restaurant)*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.food_picked_up-os.rider_at_restaurant)+EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.food_picked_up-os.rider_at_restaurant)/60 AS rider_in_restaurant_time,                        
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.rider_at_customer-os.food_picked_up)*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.rider_at_customer-os.food_picked_up)+EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.rider_at_customer-os.food_picked_up)/60 AS rider_driving_to_customer_time,                        
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM os.food_delivered-os.rider_at_customer)*60+EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered-os.rider_at_customer)+EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.food_delivered-os.rider_at_customer)/60 AS rider_at_customer_time,                        
    EXTRACT (HOUR FROM os.food_delivered-od.date)*60 + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM os.food_delivered-od.date) + EXTRACT (SECOND FROM os.food_delivered-od.date)/60 AS delivery_time,                       
    od.order_comment,                       
    od.preorder                     
    FROM dwh.pedido p                       
    LEFT JOIN dwh.order_fp o ON p.id = o.pedido_id                      
    LEFT JOIN order_steps os ON os.pedido_id = p.id                     
    LEFT JOIN assigned_riders r ON r.pedido_id = p.id                       
    LEFT JOIN dwh.moteros m ON m.id = r.motero_id                       
    LEFT JOIN dwh.sf_guard_user u ON u.id = m.sf_guard_user_id                      
    INNER JOIN dwh."Orders" od ON od.id = o.order_fp_id                     
    INNER JOIN dwh."Status" st ON st.id = od.status_id
    INNER JOIN dwh."Statusflows" stf ON stf.order_id = od.id
    INNER JOIN dwh."Vendors" ve ON od.vendor_id = ve.id                     
    WHERE u.first_name NOT IN ('TEST RIDER','Jan')                      
    and os.rider_accepted between (current_date-30) and (current_date-1)        
   GROUP BY p.id, stf.status_id, stf.date, os.rider_accepted, u.first_name, os.food_delivered, od.preorder, od.order_comment, os.rider_assigned, od.date, os.food_picked_up, os.rider_at_restaurant, o.order_fp_code, os.rider_viewed, os.rider_at_customer, os.unknown_status, st.id, ve.title
   LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: What do you mean does not work? What is the error? For this script, check parentheses align. Also, if `CASE/WHEN` statements become intricate, consider using UNION queries. If not for performance, it may help at least for readability and maintainability.

Comment: @Parfait Sorry, I have to adjust what I first said. What happens in the 'Delay' part is, it should check the initial condition (the u.first_name part) and subsequently check if it also matches any of the conditions mentioned below it (after the AND part). I think I made a mistake in my initial description of the question, it seems that the query does not take the AND part into consideration, not just the final criterion as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: @Patrick apologies, full query added now.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to be certain about your logic in the `CASE` clause, but at least the below should work because it is syntactically correct:

```
WITH order_steps AS (       
  SELECT pedido_id,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion =  0 THEN created_at END) AS rider_assigned,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion =  1 THEN created_at END) AS rider_viewed,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion =  2 THEN created_at END) AS rider_accepted,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion =  3 THEN created_at END) AS rider_at_restaurant,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion =  4 THEN created_at END) AS food_picked_up,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion =  5 THEN created_at END) AS rider_at_customer,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion =  6 THEN created_at END) AS food_delivered,
    max(CASE WHEN situacion = 10 THEN created_at END) AS unknown_status
  FROM dwh.tracking_motero
  GROUP BY 1
), assigned_riders AS (
  WITH rider_assignments AS (                     
    SELECT pedido_id, motero_id, created_at,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pedido_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
    FROM dwh.motero_pedido
  )
  SELECT pedido_id, motero_id FROM rider_assignments WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN
         (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date >= (p.fecha_prevista_entrega + interval '30 minutes')) 
      OR (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date < (os.rider_accepted + interval '5 minutes'))
    THEN 'Not Paid - Cancelled' 

    WHEN
         (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date <= (p.fecha_prevista_entrega + interval '30 minutes')) 
      OR (stf.status_id IN ('38','14','13','12','16','18') AND stf.date >= p.fecha_entrega_repartidor)
    THEN 'Paid - Cancelled'

    WHEN
        (
           (u.first_name ILIKE '%LKF%'     AND extract(epoch from os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega) > 900)
        OR (u.first_name NOT ILIKE '%LKF%' AND extract(epoch from os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega) > 1800)
        )
      AND (
        (od.preorder = '0' AND od.order_comment ILIKE '%' || u.first_name || '%'
         AND extract(epoch from os.rider_assigned - od.date) < 900)
        OR
        (od.preorder = '0' AND od.order_comment NOT ILIKE '%' || u.first_name || '%' 
         AND extract(epoch from os.rider_assigned - od.date) < 1200)
        OR
        (od.preorder = '1' AND extract(epoch from p.fecha_prevista_entrega - os.rider_assigned) > 1800)
        OR
        (extract(epoch from os.food_delivered - p.fecha_prevista_entrega) > 900)
        OR
        (extract(epoch from os.rider_at_restaurant - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor) > 180)
         AND extract(epoch from os.food_picked_up - p.fecha_entrega_repartidor) < 900)
      )
    THEN 'Delay'
    ELSE 'None' END AS payment_adj,
    p.id AS urban_ninja_id, 
    o.order_fp_code AS order_code,      
    p.total AS order_amount,
    p.paymenttype_name,     
    u.first_name AS rider_code,     
    p.direccion AS delivery_address,
    p.fecha_entrega_repartidor AS expected_pick_up_time,
    p.fecha_prevista_entrega AS expected_delivery_time,     
    od.date AS order_creation_date,     
    os.rider_assigned,      
    os.rider_viewed,
    os.rider_accepted,      
    os.rider_at_restaurant,     
    os.food_picked_up,      
    os.rider_at_customer,       
    os.food_delivered,      
    os.unknown_status,      
    st.id AS status_id,     
    st.code AS status_code,     
    st.title AS status,     
    ve.title AS vendor,     
    to_date(os.rider_assigned - od.date, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS dispatching_time,     
    to_date(os.rider_viewed - os.rider_assigned, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS rider_reaction_time,      
    to_date(os.rider_accepted - os.rider_viewed, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS rider_acceptance_time,
    to_date(os.rider_at_restaurant - os.rider_accepted, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS rider_driving_to_restaurant_time,
    to_date(os.food_picked_up - os.rider_at_restaurant, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS rider_in_restaurant_time,
    to_date(os.rider_at_customer - os.food_picked_up, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS rider_driving_to_customer_time,
    to_date(os.food_delivered - os.rider_at_customer, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS rider_at_customer_time,
    to_date(os.food_delivered - od.date, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS delivery_time,       
    od.order_comment,       
    od.preorder     
FROM dwh.pedido p       
LEFT JOIN dwh.order_fp o ON p.id = o.pedido_id      
LEFT JOIN order_steps os ON os.pedido_id = p.id     
LEFT JOIN assigned_riders r ON r.pedido_id = p.id       
LEFT JOIN dwh.moteros m ON m.id = r.motero_id       
LEFT JOIN dwh.sf_guard_user u ON u.id = m.sf_guard_user_id      
JOIN dwh."Orders" od ON od.id = o.order_fp_id     
JOIN dwh."Status" st ON st.id = od.status_id
JOIN dwh."Statusflows" stf ON stf.order_id = od.id
JOIN dwh."Vendors" ve ON od.vendor_id = ve.id     
WHERE u.first_name NOT IN ('TEST RIDER','Jan')      
  AND os.rider_accepted BETWEEN (current_date-30) AND (current_date-1)
GROUP BY p.id, stf.status_id, stf.date, os.rider_accepted, u.first_name, os.food_delivered, od.preorder,
         od.order_comment, os.rider_assigned, od.date, os.food_picked_up, os.rider_at_restaurant,
         o.order_fp_code, os.rider_viewed, os.rider_at_customer, os.unknown_status, st.id, ve.title
LIMIT 100;
```

Also check out the "shortcuts" for your `extract()` chaos: `extract (epoch from time2 - time1)` gives the number of seconds in the interval. In the `CASE` clause I converted your minutes to seconds, in the select list I used the `to_date()` function to get a nice display.

Also check your data types, you seem to be implicitly casting `integer` values to strings as in `stf.status_id` and `od.preorder`.